# Assets in Wygwam not displaying on front end in EE 2.6/Assets 2.1.1/Wygwam 2.7.1

Tags: assets, wygwam, pixelandtonic

Just updated to EE 2.6 today, also updated Assets and Wygwam to 2.1.1 and 2.7.1 respectively.

I have images in my Wygwam fields, if I var dump the raw data, the code stored looks like this: `{assets_86:{filedir_2}faculty-staff-stats.png}`

When it gets rendered, it looks like this: `http://mysite.dev/uploads/assorted/faculty-staff-stats.pngfaculty-staff-stats.png}`.

Same code worked perfectly prior to upgrading.

Comment: Traced this back to `Wygwam_helper::replace_asset_tags()`. A slight change to the regex at the top of the method fixed things for me:

Change this:
`preg_match_all("/\\{assets_(\\d*):((.*)(\\}))/uU", $data, $matches);`

To this:
`preg_match_all("/\\{assets_(\\d*):((.*?)(\\}))/uU", $data, $matches);`

Comment: Thanks Rob!  I'll go ahead and post this as a bug for us to look at.

Comment: Was this ever fixed? I am still getting this error with Wygwam 2.7.1 and Assets 2.1.3. I have found that on first publish after adding an image I get the error with the URL like described above. But, once I save again (without changing anything), the URLs are fine.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not yet fixed; does the above change get this working for you in the meantime?

Comment: I hadn't tried it yet... I didn't want to hack the module if there was a more official fix.

Comment: I've tried the above fix and unfortunately it did not work. I'm running EE 2.5.5, Assets 2.1.3 & Wygwam 2.7.1. Any chance you might be able to look into this for me @Lisa? Even with the above fix the img src renders as {assets_345:{filedir_17}dandelion.jpg}

Comment: I'm having the same issue but the same applies to me as it does to James - once I save the entry again (without changing anything), the URLs are fine. Running EE 2.5.5, Asets 2.1.3 and Wygwam 2.7.1. However the fix mentioned above worked though.

Comment: I would comment but I don't have enough rep to yet, basically I had a similar issue and filed a support request with P&T - it has been fixed in an upcoming release as Brad wrote in answer to my question [here](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/11858/1090). Hope that helps.

Comment: Had the same issue with EE 2.6.1, Assets 2.1.4, and WYGWAM 2.7.1. I applied the hotfix from Rob and it works great now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on EE 2.6, 2.6.1, or 2.6.2 and using Assets 2.1.1, you should update to the latest versions of both. If you're stubborn, Rob's fix above will work for you.

If you even more stubborn and on EE 2.5.5 or below, then stop being stubborn and update. Said with kindness in my heart.