# Not all Structure URL's are parsed from Wygwam

Tags: wygwam, structure, pixelandtonic, transcribe

If our client selects a structure managed page from the Wygwam link tool, the URL doesn't always parse, resulting in the occasional `{page_XX}` instead of the full URL. However if I drag the page that is getting link to around in the Structure tree, and place it back to where it belong the URL is updated.

I suspect this might have something to do with the Transcribe+Structure combination, as there are still a few small bugs here and there with that collaboration, but I can't tell for sure.

I'm on EE 2.5.5, Structure 3.3.8 and Wygwam 2.7

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey Magnusland - what versions of EE and all of those add-ons are you on? Can you add that to the original post?  Also, if you open your browser's debug console, do you see any JS errors?

Comment: Hi @LisaWess, I've added this now.

Comment: And no JS errors in the console.

Comment: Magnusland - is you take transcribe out of the picture, does this still occur?  Isolating where the issue is would help quite a lot.  Also, are you saving the entry while Wygwam is in its normal mode, or is it in source mode?  Thank you!

Comment: If the problem occurs when you try and reference a page from one language in a Wygwam field of a page in another language then it is probably Transcribe related.  It has to do with how Transcribe overrides the site_pages data .  If you dump out $pages['uri'] in _get_pages_mod_data method of the Wygwam_helper class you will see the issue when you search for the entry_id (page_{entry_id}) in the array.  What complicates fixing this is Transcribe also jacks up the urls in the site_pages array too. :(  I am working on a fix, but it doesn't look promising at the moment.

Comment: I'm currently experiencing this as well. No Transcribe. EE 2.9.2, WYGWAM 3.3.2, Structure 3.3.14.6

Answer (score 1):

I can say that it doesn't relate to Transcribe. I have a site where randomly some (but not all) the links set with the Wygwam Structure link browser outputs {page_XX} like you are describing. We are not using Transcribe.

I am also on EE 2.5.5, I was on Structure 3.3.8 (now on 3.3.10), and Wygwam 2.7 (now 2.7.1).

I'm not really sure if the upgrade to Structure or Wygwam has fixed the issue. I don't have a way to reliably reproduce it. But I have seen the issue, and am also concerned.

Hopefully that helps figure things out.

Comment: James, if you see this crop up again, can you let me know?  Leaving it in its broken state may also help.  Also, could you try the modification here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/assets-in-wygwam-not-displaying-on-front-end-in-ee-2-6-assets-2-1-1-wygwam-2-7-1 and see if it helps?

Comment: I'll keep a look out for sure. I can't say they'd be too thrilled for me to keep it in the broken state... but perhaps I can do a DB dump of that cell. I did see the modification in that other post. I was actually the one that responded. I'm a little hesitant though to hack the module and would prefer of course an official fix. I just don't want to introduce potentially more issues by using the hack.

Comment: That hack is temporary, it is reported as a bug so we'll get an official fix out there.  You can always back up your files to roll back the hack if it doesn't work; it should not impact upgrades though.  And yes,a db dump in the broken state would be good. :)

Comment: ok, I found an example with both the Structure page link not resolving and an Asset linked image not resolving. Where should I send it to?