# Assets + Wygwam: Wrong URL on Front End

Tags: assets, wygwam, image, uploads

I've got a Wygwam field that's using Assets for image uploads. I can upload images and they display fine in the entry form, but when I save the entry and then go look at it on the front end, the image URL is wrong. Here's an example:

```
Correct URL: /uploads/news/Picture_5.png
Actual URL: /uploads/news/Picture_5.pngPicture_5.png%7D
```

The strange thing is if I go back into the entry and just resave it, it fixes the problem.

I'm using the latest versions of Assets, Wygwam, and EE.

Comment: Andrew what do you have set for the URL in your File Upload preference?  Or is this using an External source?  Also, can you let us know the version for EE, Assets, and Wygwam?  Thank you!

Comment: The URL for that particular file directory is set to /uploads/news/

EE version 2.6.1
Assets version 2.1.3
Wygwam version 2.7.1

Thanks!

Comment: What does your source view look like in Wygwam after uploading a file, whlie it's in its broken state?

Comment: Everything looks fine in Wygwam. The URL is correct, and there are no HTML errors.

Comment: Also, it's probably worth noting that this is what's getting stored in the DB: <img alt="" src="{assets_301:{filedir_7}Picture_5.png}" style="width: 402px; height: 299px; " />

Comment: Upon resaving, the entry in the DB gets changed to <img alt="" src="{filedir_7}Picture_5.png" style="width: 402px; height: 299px; " />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a duplicate question. [This post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/assets-in-wygwam-not-displaying-on-front-end-in-ee-2-6-assets-2-1-1-wygwam-2-7-1) has an answer which worked for me.