# Adding images in Wygwam is Flakey

Tags: wygwam

I have Wygwam and Assets. In a Matrix cell I upload and insert an image via Wygwam/Assets. After I publish, no image. Sometimes I get the alt tag text, sometimes nothing, as in no img tag. If I persist by opening the entry and re-publishing, maybe a couple of times, I get the image eventually. Obviously, I can't hand this over to a client.

No problem with Assets when it's its own custom field or in Matrix as an Assets cell; just goofy in conjunction with Wygwam.

All add-ons and EE are up-to-date as of May 25, 2013.

Rick

**Further to:** I created a test channel with only a Wygwam custom field. I created a template that only renders this field. I created some entries, some with just an image in the Wygwam field, one with both text and an image in the Wygwam field. I used different images from different Assets folders each time. In all cases, the rendered img tag is wrong.

It renders:

```
<img alt="wac" src="http://wac.artsforall.ca/images/uploads/files/General/WAC-logo-thumbnail.jpgGeneral/WAC-logo-thumbnail.jpg}" style="width: 144px; height: 131px;" />
```

See that extra "General/WAC-logo-thumbnail.jpg}"? It's wrong. It doesn't show in the field's source view. It's there on the rendered page when viewing source.

**Further further to:** If I go back to the entry and Submit again, then the resulting link is correct and the image displays.

Which is not, of course, a solution!

Comment: An answer (but not a final solution) can be found here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/assets-in-wygwam-not-displaying-on-front-end-in-ee-2-6-assets-2-1-1-wygwam-2-7-1

Comment: Richard, that is reported as a bug but we have not yet published a fix for it.  Is the temporary solution working for you?

Comment: Sorry, I was gone for a while. Lisa, the temporary fix is working.