# Assets in Wygwam only inserting {assets_X} on first save

Tags: assets, wygwam

So, similar to [this question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/assets-in-wygwam-not-displaying-on-front-end-in-ee-2-6-assets-2-1-1-wygwam-2-7-1) when using Assets in a Wygwam field I am having to re-save an entry to get the image to output on the frontend. When I check what is getting saved to the db I get `{assets_132:{filedir_5}image.jpg}` the first time, and `{filedir_5}image.jpg` the second time.

It doesn't matter if I make the changes described in the comments of [9631](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/assets-in-wygwam-not-displaying-on-front-end-in-ee-2-6-assets-2-1-1-wygwam-2-7-1#comment11273_9631), the problem is exactly the same.

Also, if I save an entry that already has an image in it that uses a `{filedir_X}image.jpg` type url, it doesn't get converted to the `{assets_X)` method. So for example if I upgrade Wygwam and Assets from an older version and then go and save the entry to get the image urls to update, they stay in their original states. To get them to change I have to delete the image and re-add it from the file browser, then they will break for the first save as described above.

I am using EE 2.6.1, Assets 2.1.3 and Wygwam 2.7.1 and running this locally with php v 5.4.13.

This is all happened after an upgrade from EE 2.4.0, Assets 1.1.5 and Wygwam 2.5.

---

EDIT:
I am also unable to move any files around in Assets once they have been added to a Wygwam field in this manner. The Wygwam references don't get updated once the file has been moved.

Comment: Just bumping this really, anyone out there have a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in the latest version of Wygwam that will be fixed in the next release.  Sending you the patched files in the support ticket in the meantime.