# Assets URL in Low Variables Wygwam field not displaying on Front end

Tags: assets, wygwam, pixelandtonic, low-variables

Similar to [this post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/assets-in-wygwam-not-displaying-on-front-end-in-ee-2-6-assets-2-1-1-wygwam-2-7-1) I'm getting incorrect file paths being displayed on the front end when using Assets from within Wygwam. Unlike that post I'm actually getting this rendered on the front end:

`{assets_104:{filedir_1}News/3F1A0399_1.jpg}`

I've tried the fix referred to in the comments to no avail.

It doesn't matter how many times I save the entry, so I don't think it's the same issue described [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11136/assets-in-wygwam-only-inserting-assets-x-on-first-save/11858#11858)

Another difference I believe is probably key here is that the Wygwam filed is a Low Variables field type.

I'm running EE v2.5.5, [Low Variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables) v2.3.5, [Assets](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets) v2.1.4 & [Wygwam](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wygwam) 3.1.2.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the tag syntax, not the var syntax? So `{exp:low_variables:single var="my_wygwam_var"}` instead of `{my_wygwam_var}`?

Comment: Oh wow, so simple! Thanks @Low. Do you want to change your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make sure extra processing is done before the var is put in the template, use the **tag syntax** rather than the variable syntax:

```
{exp:low_variables:single var="my_wygwam_var"}
```