# Assets Image Path Issue with Wygwam on Front-end/View Entry Page

Tags: ee2, assets, wygwam

EE 2.6.1
Assets 2.3.1
Wygwam 3.3

We are having an issue where images from Assets are added to a Wygwam field, but do not display on the front-end or view entry page after save. They do appear fine within the Wygwam field on the Publish/Edit page.

A screenshot and corresponding HTML output looks like the following:

```
<img alt="" src="{assets_32:http://mydomain.com/uploads/myimagename.png}" style="width: 491px; height: 208px;">
```

[image]

I tried implementing the fix [found here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/assets-in-wygwam-not-displaying-on-front-end-in-ee-2-6-assets-2-1-1-wygwam-2-7-1), but it did not resolve the issue. The assets tag is still not parsing.

Comment: Might be worth shooting an email to support@pixelandtonic.com :)

Comment: No problem Andris, will do. Thought this might be a good place to start :)

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'm having the same problem, except I'm using:  
  
EE 2.9.2  
Assets 2.5  
Wygwam 3.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the same problem as in [this thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12928/assets-url-in-low-variables-wygwam-field-not-displaying-on-front-end). Low's solution should help you. He said:

> To make sure extra processing is done before the var is put in the
>   template, use the tag syntax rather than the variable syntax:
>   `{exp:low_variables:single var="my_wygwam_var"}`

So try using 

`{exp:low_variables:single var="my_wygwam_var"}`

Rather than

`{my_wygwam_var}`